# How change Compare Multiple Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 codes to change the color to Textbox, and unfortunately none of them work. What's wrong here? Why the code is not good. Every time I try the code, not worked, The first code changes the color to Textbox if there is a value between 1 and 7, and the second changes the value in ascending order from the lowest to the highest and assigns a corresponding color. Please tell me if these 2 codes are written correctly, or there is a write error.

Code 1: Image: http://www.imagebam.com/image/5ac5ee1073004874

```
Public Class TextBoxColors
    Private ColorTable As Dictionary(Of String, Color) = New Dictionary(Of String, Color)()
    Public Sub New()
        ColorTable.Add("1", Color.Red)
        ColorTable.Add("2", Color.Aqua)
        ColorTable.Add("3", Color.Chocolate)
        ColorTable.Add("4", Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        ColorTable.Add("5", Color.BurlyWood)
        ColorTable.Add("6", Color.BlueViolet)
        ColorTable.Add("7", Color.DarkBlue)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetColor(ColorMap As String) As Color
        Return If(ColorTable.Keys.Contains(ColorMap), ColorTable(ColorMap), Color.White)
    End Function
End Class

Private txtColor As TextBoxColors = New TextBoxColors()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each txtDraw As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(txt) txt.Name.StartsWith("txtDraw"))
        AddHandler txtDraw.TextChanged,
            Sub()
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDraw.Text) Then
                    txtDraw.BackColor = txtColor.GetColor(txtDraw.Text)
                End If
            End Sub
    Next
End Sub
```

Code 2: This 2nd code must be changed based on my text box, which starts with SumtxtDraw
- Image: http://www.imagebam.com/image/92a4091073004904

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     FillColorList()
 End Sub

Private Sub ColorTextBoxes()
    FillTextBoxList(16, 23)
    Dim SortedList As List(Of TextBox) = SortList()
    Dim index As Integer
    For Each txt As TextBox In SortedList
         txt.BackColor = lstColor(index)
         index += 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FillColorList()
    lstColor.Add(Color.Red) 'for lowest number
    lstColor.Add(Color.BlanchedAlmond)
    lstColor.Add(Color.PaleGreen)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Chartreuse)
    lstColor.Add(Color.CadetBlue)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Orange)
    lstColor.Add(Color.DarkMagenta)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Violet) 'for highest number
End Sub

Private Sub FillTextBoxList(StartNumber As Integer, EndNumber As Integer)
    lstTextBox.Clear()
    For suffix = StartNumber To EndNumber
        lstTextBox.Add(DirectCast(Controls("TextBox" & suffix.ToString), TextBox))
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SortList() As List(Of TextBox)
    Dim orderedList = From txt In lstTextBox Order By CInt(txt.Text) Descending Select txt '$"{scorer.Score} - {scorer.Name}"
    Dim SortedList As List(Of TextBox) = orderedList.ToList
    Return SortedList
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ColorTextBoxes()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add to the question more information, like where the code fails. For example, looking at your first code I found nothing wrong, so I've tried it on a sample app and it worked OK, so I don't know what are your doubts.

Comment: We edited the post, so we introduced the images.

Comment: You're saying that, for code 1 for example, your code doesn't even compile? What errors you get? What version of VS/.NET are you using?

Comment: Use Visual Basic 2008, (VB 2008). Is that likely to be the cause?

Comment: Maybe, VB 2008 has 10 years already now, and you are using some "new" stuff, maybe they were not implemented back then. Why don't you use Visual Studio 2017 Community? It's free. That's the version I'm using and the first code worked here.

Comment: If the project was done make in VB2008, if I migrate to another, will my project work the same way? or what should I do?

Comment: Yes, I wrote you a comment in the question where this code come from. The VB.Net version of VS 2008 doesn't support the Lambda (the `Sub()` in the `AddHandler` statement). I'll modify the original code.

Comment: Need to add `Private lstColor As New List(Of Color)` and 
    `Private lstTextBox As New List(Of TextBox)` at the Form level (Class level). So sorry, I am adding to my original answer.

Comment: I thought I posted this code in answer to a question from @Angga Sillvert. Do you have 2 accounts or are you both working on the same project?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921449/compare-value-multiple-textbox-vb-net/53925520#53925520 for the edited code.